# Accessing Azure VNet from Azure Logic App

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-virtual-network, azure-api-management

I have a Logic App and, in my workflow, I need to call a service that is deployed in a vnet. So far my research points me to using API Management to talk to the VNet resource, or to reimplement my workflow as an Azure Function.

Since the resources, blog posts, etc, I am finding are several months-old, I thought I asked you here. Are these indeed the options I have?

Comment: What kind of things are trying to do ? accessing files on a VM ?  could you explain a little bit more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asumming that:

1. Your VNET is locked down
2. Your service is an HTTP service (either RESTful or SOAP)
3. the VNET doesn't allow HTTP calls from outside.

Then you have a couple of options:

1. Use [On-Premises Data Gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-gateway-install). The OPDG is an agent that you can deploy on a VM in your VNET and would allow you to call HTTP endpoints. You need to create a Custom Connector which uses the OPDG. This is in preview, and unfortunately the documentation is not there yet, but I've implemented it. OPDG has no cost, you pay just for the VM and traffic.
2. Deploy your APIM within the VNET and deploy App Gateway on top which will allow access from outside the VNET. This requires more work (networking) and you will need to pay more.
3. Deploy APIM outside the VNET, get your own static IP, and only allow HTTPS traffic from your APIM to your VNET. Some people might not like this option, but you can consider it.

HTH